# bootstrap nav bar shows no CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get the navbar to work. I got the nav bar code from w3schools. But all that happens is that it will show the navbar, but without any css applied, and it looks very wrong. 
here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Html Editor 0.1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="meineStyles.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
      <br>
      <div class="container jumbotron shadowdiv">
         <form id ="kekform" >
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" name="comment" form="kekform" id="textarea1" 
                 onkeyup="showUserJquery(this.value)"></textarea>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6" id="divfortext">
                  <div id="eindiv" style="vertical-align:top"><b id="test"></b></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                  </td>
                  <td >
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>  
                     <button onclick="changeColor()" type="button" style="color: red"  >Farbe ändern</button>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="radio" form="kekform" value="htmlno" name="htmlenable"   checked="checked" id="htmlno">
                     <label for="htmlno">No HTML</label>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type="radio" form="kekform" value="htmlyes" name="htmlenable" id="htmlyes">
                     <label for="htmlyes">Yes HTML</label>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </form>
         <br> <br>
         <br>
         <br>
      </div>


   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="meineScripte.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

   </body>
</html>
```

Here is a jsfiddle for you, `meineScripte.js` and `meineStyles.css` are in the corresponding part. https://jsfiddle.net/m7kq6p9q/
Yes, I already tried without my own .js and css, but it still doesn't work. I also checked with chrome's developer tools if the bootstrap files are correctly loaded.

You can clearly see that the navbar is not looking like it's supposed to. This is where I got it from: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: @Script47 Did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the documentation provided [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/), I've been able to create a working dummy for you.

**Note:** W3Schools' Bootstrap tutorial is based on version 3.X.X and you are using Bootstrap 4.0.0 hence there probably is some compatibility issues, as a result you'd rather make use of Bootstrap's documentation instead of W3Schools.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Live Example**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Laxy6gmy/)

Comment: Thanks it works now, I guess you are correct with it being a compatibility issue